# Auto Select colour Swatch when configurable product page loads

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, javascript, color-swatches

I have a configurable product with one colour and different sizes, both these are set as required fields.

I've set the colour attribute as not required, but then it wont show up when I create a configurable product and wont show on the product page.

How do I get the colour swatch to be automatically selected when the product page loads?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How do I get the colour swatch to be automatically selected when the product page loads?

Answer (score 0):

Open this file from app\design\frontend[your package][your theme]\template\catalog\product\view\type\options\configurable.phtml

Now add the below javascript code :-

```
 function fireEvent(element,event){
if (document.createEventObject){
// dispatch for IE
var evt = document.createEventObject();
return element.fireEvent('on'+event,evt)
}
else{
// dispatch for firefox + others
var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
evt.initEvent(event, true, true ); // event type,bubbling,cancelable
return !element.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
}
Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
spConfig.settings[0].selectedIndex = 1;
obj = spConfig.settings[0]; // this grabs the first select item
Event.observe(obj,'change',function(){});
fireEvent(obj,'change'); // this simulates selecting the first option, which triggers
spConfig.settings[1].selectedIndex = 1; // this selects the first option of the second attribute drop menu
});
```

after this code :-

```
var spConfig = new Product.Config(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
```

and flush magento cache and check.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go with jQuery in magento
so you can trigger with click on color swatches on document ready

```
jQuery("document").ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {  
       jQuery("#configurable_swatch li:last-child a span").trigger('click');
  },100);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want an extension, you can refer:
https://github.com/magepow/magento-2-configurable-preselect